# Getting same url for all product load by id

Tags: magento2

i am tring to get product name and url according to product id but get return  first product url for all but product names are getting right.here is my code.please help me.thank you.

in phtml page

```
 <?php  foreach ($question_list as $value){ ?>
                <div class="QuestionDiv">
                    <div class="reviewInfo"><strong><?php echo __('Q : ');?><label><?php echo $value->getQuestionNote(); ?></label></strong></div>
                    <div class="infoDiv">
                        <?php 
                            $id = $value->getProductId();
                            if($value->getQuestionStatus() == 0){
                                echo  __('Status : pending');
                            }elseif($value->getQuestionStatus() == 1){
                                    echo  __('Status : published');
                            }else{
                                    echo  __('Status : rejected');
                            } 
                            $productObj = $block->getProductDetails($id);
                            echo  __('  || Product name : ').$productObj->getName();
                            echo  __('  || Producturl  : ').$productObj->getProductUrl();
                        ?>
                    </div>
               </div> 

<?php      } ?>
```

**in block page**

```
public function getProductDetails($id){

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
    return $productObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use object Manager directly

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
private $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getProductDetails($productId){
    return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, null, true);
}
```

Use method getById and the last **set last parameter to true** which will **forceReload** to create new instance of product model every time. [Refer this for more details](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/958164/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php#L227-L230)

Answer (score 0):

In your block you should create an object for the Product model, Please use below code and checked it here.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to load product by id

```
public function getProductDetails($id){

    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    return $product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use create instead of get :

```
public function getProductDetails($id){

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
    return $productObj;
}
```